# DIV (overlay) slide out on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to create an "overlay" effect on my website with some information in it.

I have been trying to find information relative to this subject but haven't had any luck yet.

What I basically am looking for is something that does this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vhIR.png

I've been messing around for a bit but when I try to apply it to my website, it scales horribly and generally doesn't work very well.

Would anyone know any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you on the right track.

index.html

```
<div id="your_website">
    <button>Open overlay</button>
</div>
<div id="overlay">
    <p>Add anything here</p>
    <button>Close overlay</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
#your_website {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
}

#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#overlay.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#your_website button").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").addClass("active");
});

$("#overlay button").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").removeClass("active");
});
```

Note that you need jQuery for this. Basically you create a hidden element, and then you make it 'active' and position in on top of everything other. Do not forget to add a button to close it.

Comment: I've had something working already, but it was just a horrible mess to scale with the website. I'm going to try this in a second and let you know how it goes!

Comment: I did not notice you needed a sliding overlay. Have a look into this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fxj1h3of/1/

Comment: Im not quite sure if I understand it correctly, but do you want the overlay to be arrow'ish ?
NP, we're always overthinking simple things in life ;)

Comment: It works now, but as you can see in the pictures it needs to slide out a bit more than the screen's length (the points leaves the screen) as I have it now; this cuts off part off the back of the svg like so [example](http://i.imgur.com/B4VzH8j.png)  Would you know a solution to this problem? .... NVM! got that, too now! Thank you! <3